# How do I disable specific sensors for a SonarQube project?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have SonarQube analysis running for our .NET projects with Visual Studio Test Coverage enabled. Is there any way to prevent specific sensors from running during analysis?

For example, Jacoco runs even though there is no Java code to analyse, and we already have VS code coverage enable so we don't need other coverage sensors to run for this project.

I've had a look through the Quality Profiles and Gates but I couldn't find anything related to sensors. Excluding the `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` setting also has no effect since it just reverts to its built-in defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the **Jacoco Sensor** cannot be disabled from the scanner in the current SonarQube version (v.10.x - Jul 2023).

To clarify, Jacoco it's not a plugin, it comes pre-installed by default as a **sensor**, and cannot be uninstalled.

As a workaround, you can ignore the scans, or create patterns for coverage exclusions `**/**` for example.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT after comments:**

JaCoCo is PLUGIN, which means that you can [turn it on](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/java-test-coverage/#single-module-maven-project) and turn it off. In this case, either you included it or there is a major bug in SonarQube.

**The rest of the answer is related to disabling code coverage:**

[Here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/disable-coverage-test/2336) you can find a thread with a similar question, and [here is an accepted answer](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/disable-coverage-test/2336/8) for this issue:

[image: Stoled from forum]

Also, a few answers later the same person commented:

> This should remove the whole section altogether.

Comment: I don't want to disable test coverage - I want to disable a specific sensor that tries to run a coverage report that does not apply to my project. Jacoco is used for Java. We already have test coverage for .NET and Visual Studio. if we disable this, we will no longer get coverage reports.

Comment: @ilitirit Is this related to Java or .NET? Do you have a combined repo with both Java and .NET?
SonarQube does not generate code coverage by it self, you must use third-party libs for it. Details can be found here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/java-test-coverage/

The second sentence on the link said that! Either way, you can remove third-party libs easily...

Comment: I think you misunderstand how this process works. Jacoco is a *SonarQube plugin*, so the sensor is enabled for all projects *regardless of the language*. There is no 3rd Party lib in MY project that I want to disable. I want to disable the *Jacoco SonarQube SENSOR*.

Comment: @ilitirit Plugin by default means that something is not part of the base system, but it is something that you can add/remove whenever you want. If something is called a plugin, and you can't remove it from the base system, THERM PLUGIN IS NOT CORRECT. Further, all of the tutorials for JaCoCo literally said that you must include JaCoCo dependency and must set action (here is the official link https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/java-test-coverage/ ). Either way, your problem is a major bug on Sonarqube or you have somewhere defined using of JaCoCo.